# What is my line integral answer incorrect?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, plane-curves

EDIT:  Is my computation not correct, possibly because the parametrization that I used *requires* x,y to be on the xy-plane?

If so, can I adjust from here, and not start over?  I.e., is there some sort of rotation that I can apply?  Although a rotation would not help with changing the *value* of the answer, I think...

My work:

I computed the answer to be $3\pi$, while the answer is supposed to $\sqrt{3} \pi$.

The integral is

$$\int_C zdx + xdy + zdz$$

where C is the circle of intersection of the plane $x+y+z=0$, and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

My work:

I wrote $x=rcos(\theta)$, $y=rsin(\theta)$, $z=-x-y$  $=-rcos(\theta)-rsin(\theta)$.  Note that I used radius = $r=1$.

Then, I computed $d\theta$, in terms of $dx$, $dy$, and $dz$.

Finally, I computed an ordinary Riemman integral of $(1+sin^2(\theta)$)$d\theta$, from 0 to $2\pi$, and got $3\pi$ as my answer.

Have I overlooked something important?  Am I off by a scaling factor?  Or perhaps I paramaterized incorrectly.  My computations look straightforward and ok, though.

Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Ah, I was hopeful that I can go home now to sleep @JohnMa :-( Can you offer a hint?  Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parametization of $C$ is not correct. It just does not satisfy $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$.

To find a correct one, note that $(1, 1, 1)$ is the normal vector of the plane $x+y+ z = 0$. Then one can find two orthonormal vectors $e_1, e_2$ such that both of them are prependicular to $(1, 1, 1)$, then $C$ can be parametrized by

$$\theta \mapsto  \cos\theta e_1 +\sin \theta e_2.$$

I think the rest will not be difficult. (After some works from the OP, the parametrization of $C$ is given by

$$\begin{split} \theta &\mapsto \cos\theta \frac{1}{\sqrt 6}(-1,-1, 2) + \sin\theta \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (1, -1, 0) \\
&= \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt 6} \cos\theta +\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \sin \theta, -\frac{1}{\sqrt 6} \cos\theta -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \sin \theta, \frac{2}{\sqrt 6} \cos\theta\right)
\end{split}$$

Thus

$$x = -\frac{1}{\sqrt 6} \cos\theta +\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \sin \theta,\ \ y = -\frac{1}{\sqrt 6} \cos\theta -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \sin \theta,\ \ z = \frac{2}{\sqrt 6} \cos\theta.$$

Comment: Hi @JohnMa, I have a few questions:  did you mean to say that the parametrization does not satisfy the plane equation x+y+z=0, and that it *does* satisfy the unit-sphere equation?  Also, is the goal to find two orthonormal vectors that *lie on the plane*?  And then these two orthonormal vectors could serve as our coordinate axes, like the role of x and y in the xy-plane.

Comment: But the algorithm that I have in mind is Gram-Schmidt, but although the algorithm will produce an orthogonal set, how do we know the two new vectors gotten from starting with (1,1,1) will be orthogonal *and* lie on the plane?  Is it because we are only in 3-dimensions, so it must be the case -- since (1,1,1) is already pointing in one direction, this is fixed, and from here, there are only two orthogonal directions left to take.

Comment: What do you think?  If my intuition is all good, then why do you have *addition* of angles, and not $cos(\theta)$, $sin(\theta)$ ... separately?  Thanks so much, @JohnMa

Comment: @Lebron : I mean $(\cos\theta, \sin \theta, -\cos\theta - \sin\theta)$ satisfy $x+y+z= 0$ but not $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$.  And yes, you can pick any two vectors $v_1, v_2$ so that $v_1, v_2 , (1,1,1)$ are linearly independent and then use Gram-Schmidt (and yes, after that you got two vectors in that plane). But in this situation it is easy to spot two vectors that are perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$. Using this two will save you a lot of time.

Comment: $\cos\theta e_1 + \sin\theta e_2$ is addition of two vectors, such like $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ is really $\cos\theta (1,0) + \sin\theta (0,1)$. @LebronJames

Comment: Hi @JohnMa, I think I almost got it:  I spotted two vectors easily as you suggested.  Then I normalized these vectors.  I am guessing that since these two vectors now lie on the plane and have *unit* length, then it is *on* on the unit-shere, which is what we want, in order to satisfy both equations.  Is this true, @JohnMa?

Comment: I feel it's not necessarily true:  these unit orthogonal vectors don't necessarily start from the center of the disk of intersection, right?  My two vectors were $\vec u_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt {6}} (-1,-1,2)$ and $\vec u_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (0,1,-1)$.  All three vectors I checked were linearly independent (with matrix row reductions.)  So, my main concern is that, are these unit vectors on the plane *also* on the sphere because of their unit length?  Like, if they are unit vectors away from the center of the plane, they could point outside of the unit sphere.  What do you think? Thanks @JohnMa

Comment: Also, how do we proceed with a parameterization?  Does $\vec u_1$ and $\vec u_2$ play the role of x,y?  so that the parameterization is ($\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}cos(\theta), \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}sin(\theta)$)?  Using the normalizing constants of the $\vec u_1$ and $\vec u_2$ as my radius = r.  Is this ok?  Thanks @JohnMa

Comment: It seems that the dot product of $u_1$ and $u_2$ is not zero? @LebronJames

Comment: Ah, yes, so take $\vec u_2$ instead to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,-1,0)$ @JohnMa

Comment: Cool, then the parametrization would be $\cos\theta u_1 + \sin\theta u_2 =\cos\theta \frac{1}{\sqrt 6} (-1,-1,2) + \sin\theta \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (1,-1,0) = \cdots $. @LebronJames

Comment: So, dx = $du_1$ , dy = $du_2$ , and dz = $du_3$?  Now, with these three equalities, compute the $d\theta$ term?  What do you think @JohnMa?

Comment: @LebronJames Please see the edit.

Comment: That is awesome -- and tricky!  Can I please ask you one final question?  How do you know that those two orthonormal vectors on the plane will *be on the sphere too*?  I know it's argument that they are unit length, hence, point on the sphere, hence the vectors are *on* the sphere.  Now all that's left is to run $\theta$ from 0 to $2\pi$ to achieve our line integral.  But how do we know those vectors are on the sphere?  What if ...they stick out of the sphere...or stick inside....etc...?  Thanks so much, @JohnMa

Comment: If you calculate the length of $u(\theta) = \cos\theta u_1 + \sin\theta u_2$, it's $\| u(\theta)\|^2 = \cos^2 \theta \|u_1\|^2 + \sin^2\theta \|u_2\|^2$ as $\{u_1, u_2\}$ are orthnormal. (It's the same, again to answering why $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ lies in the unit circle). @LebronJames

Comment: Oh, even easier!  I just noticed the vectors satisfy the unit-sphere equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1$!  :-)  oh, gosh... I must sleep now.  it's 7am here.  And write all of this up first thing when I wake up - with my iced chai latte.  Thank you so, so, much @JohnMa!!

Comment: I really appreciate your time and patience :-)  Have a great night @JohnMa :-)

Comment: Actually...of course it would satisfy the unit-sphere equation -- the vectors are of unit-norm.  So, I just don't understand why the vectors on the plane, *have* to be on the sphere.  Satisfying the sphere equation is a given, because the vectors are unit length, but what if they point out of the sphere?  There's no assumption that the two vectors in the plane are originating from the **center** of the plane, @JohnMa

Comment: There is no concept of "origin" on this plane @JohnMa ...and that is concerning, don't you think? The vectors may not point **on** the sphere :-(

Comment: .....But they do point out from the center $(0,0,0)$, if it starts from somewhere else, say $\vec p = (p_1, p_2, p_3)$, I have to write $\vec p + \cos\theta u_1 + \sin \theta u_2$ instead. @LebronJames

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I think so!  So, the way we've expressed it, the two vectors point from the origin, just the rules of beginning linear algebra.  And since they both have unit length **and** the plane passes **through** the origin, then vectors start can be viewed as starting from (0,0,0), and, with only unit-length, ending up **on** the sphere!  Am I correct, @JohnMa?  I'm sorry :-(

Comment: Yes you are correct. @LebronJames

Comment: Ahhh..ok awesome - thanks so much @JohnMa!!  I realllyyyy should sleep, I've been pulling too many consecutive all-nighters in the library.  Have a great night!! :-)

Comment: Have a good sleep! See you soon. @LebronJames

Comment: Hi @JohnMa, I have wrote it all up and got the correct answer :-).  I was wondering whether I could just ask you a couple of final questions so that I know for certain that I understand this sort of problem now?  a)  The generalized paramterization of a circle on a 3D-plane (not necessarily the xy-plane) was $rcos(\theta) \vec u_1 + rsin(\theta) \vec u_2$.  In our case radius = r was easily taken to be 1.

Comment: But, what if the circle of intersection C was with this plane and a, say, radius-5 sphere?  Does the parameterization change to $5cos(\theta) \vec u_1 + 5sin(\theta) \vec u_2$?  Can it instead be $cos(\theta) 5\vec u_1 + sin(\theta) 5\vec u_2$?  I.e., stretch the coordinate vectors *first*, then take linear combinations with these newly dilated vectors, with coefficients cosine and sine, respectively.

Comment: Are both of these parameterizations equivalent?  The coefficients, cosine and sine, obviously aren't linear, so I want to be careful here not to make any linearity-type assumptions, so I just wanted to see what you think too.  And b) you chose the normal vector to the plane as (1,1,1).  This goes back to good old multivariable calculus.  Given a plane ax+by+cz = d, the normal vector $\vec n$ can just be read off from the coefficients of x, y, and z, I think. And, the r.h.s., d, does *not* have to be 0, right?  Thanks so much, @JohnMa

Comment: Your formulae are all correct (if $u_1, u_2$ are orthonormal). $\cos\theta 5 $ and $5\cos\theta$ are really the same thing! And also yes, that $(1, 1, 1)$ is read off directly from $x+y+ z = \text{whatever}$. @LebronJames

Comment: Ah, now that you say it that way -- of course.  I am just being paranoid.  Thanks so much for your time on this problem.  I learned a ton from you!  Talk soon @JohnMa!  :-)